# SQL Server : join number between different date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have 2 tables like this:

```
num   datetime    color
...   ........    .....
40   2007/07/07   red  
40   2012/12/01   white   

name   datetime   num
....   ........   ...
Tom   2008/01/22  40
Tom   2014/02/27  40
```

How I can do inner join on those tables like this?

```
name       date     num   color
....   ..........   ...  ......
Tom    2008/01/22   40    red
Tom    2014/02/31   40    white
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is the logic behind scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest that you want all rows from second table and colors from first table where date is less than in second one and is max. If so:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE
    (
      num INT ,
      dt DATETIME ,
      color NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )
DECLARE @t2 TABLE
    (
      num INT ,
      dt DATETIME ,
      name NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

INSERT  INTO @t1
VALUES  ( 40, '20070707', 'red' ),
        ( 40, '20121201', 'white' )

INSERT  INTO @t2
VALUES  ( 40, '20080122', 'Tom' ),
        ( 40, '20140228', 'Tom' )

SELECT  t2.name ,
        t2.dt ,
        t2.num ,
        c.color
FROM    @t2 t2
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                t1.color
                      FROM      @t1 t1
                      WHERE     t2.num = t1.num
                                AND t1.dt < t2.dt
                      ORDER BY  t1.dt DESC
                    ) c
```

Output:

```
name    dt                      num color
Tom     2008-01-22 00:00:00.000 40  red
Tom     2014-02-28 00:00:00.000 40  white
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0 ))RNO 
    FROM #TABLE1
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0 ))RNO
    FROM #TABLE2
)
SELECT C2.NAME,C2.DATETIME,C2.NUM,C1.COLOR 
FROM CTE C1
JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C1.RNO=C2.RNO and C1.NUM=C2.NUM
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a920/1) to view result

For **SQL SERVER 2000** you can use the below code

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TABLE1 T2 WHERE T1.COLOR<T2.COLOR)RNO 
    FROM #TABLE1 T1
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TABLE1 T2 WHERE T1.datetime<T2.datetime)RNO
    FROM #TABLE2 T1
)
SELECT C2.NAME,C2.DATETIME,C2.NUM,C1.COLOR 
FROM CTE C1
JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C1.RNO=C2.RNO and C1.NUM=C2.NUM
```

Comment: that will give 4 rows

Comment: Check now. @Giorgi Nakeuri

Comment: Check now. Updated @user3775010

Comment: haha~i can't use the ROW_NUMBER(), because i useing sql server 2000

Comment: Updated for SQL 2000 @user3775010

Comment: Please add necessary tag from ur next question. You had tagged just **SQL Server**. No one will know the version. So add the version of SQL server from next question ie, SQL Server 2000 @user3775010